# Hyperledger - Docker swarm fails when deploying to multiple hosts

Tags: docker, deployment, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f). I ran `sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr <myip>`  on 1st ubuntu machine. And then I took the manager join-token and ran it on 2nd ubuntu machine and it is able to join as manager.

But the problem starts when i run `docker network create --attachable --driver overlay my-net` on 1st machine, it gives me following error:

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = The swarm does not have a leader. It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than half of the managers are online.
```

If I run the above command to create network before joining the 2nd node, the network gets created successfully and the 2nd node also gets joined to the 1st swarm node. But when I do anything on the 1st Ubuntu machine, I get the same error on it.

Both Ubuntu machines are in same network and can be `pinged` by each other.

Ubuntu version - 17.1 64 bit

Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

Docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471

Comment: Can you add the full list of commands (including which host) you are running in order?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the tutorial is off as you will only end up with two managers and that is not enough to form a quorum.  You can either add an additional manager node or simply create a single manager (`docker swarm init`) and then join a single worker using the command that is output as part of the response to `docker swarm init`.  You should SKIP the `docker swarm join-token manager` step from the tutorial.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I got your point. But I have to do some deployments on the second machine as manager only. And if I promote the workers, the same error occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the IP of your Ubuntu Machine.
Machine->Settings->nNetwork->select Attached to Bridged Adapter.
restart your machine.